# Not able to add filters on getItemsCollection in admin order page

Tags: magento2, collection, model, order-items, order-collection

I am implementing a feature, where I need to filter the order item list in order admin page. I have checked and found the list is getting from method getItemsCollection(). But when I am trying to filter the items collection, its not working.

Then for further debugging, I have tried to add filter in getItemsCollection() method of Magento\Sales\Model\Order class.

```
public function getItemsCollection($filterByTypes = [], $nonChildrenOnly = false)
{
    $collection = $this->_orderItemCollectionFactory->create()->setOrderFilter($this);

    if ($filterByTypes) {
        $collection->filterByTypes($filterByTypes);
    }
    if ($nonChildrenOnly) {
        $collection->filterByParent();
    }

    if ($this->getId()) {
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->setOrder($this);
            $this->productOption->add($item);
        }
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Here when I added filter using below code, it was working if it added before foreach but if I add below code just before return, its not working.

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('custom_variable', 'value');
```

If anyone faced this issue earlier or know why this is happening please let me know.

Comment: print query log and check if your custom_variable is there or not

Comment: It is there and I have printed the query. Query is prepared correctly and getSize() is giving me correct number. But items are not getting filtered.

Comment: If you can print the query, you can run it directly on your database, then you can read/analyze the SQL to see where it doesn't match your requirement.